# Can't get user profile in Linkedin using oauth

Tags: linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

I'm using ouath to login and it's ok, but I'm also need to store user profile link and here I get a problem. I'm using getProfile() method from oauth and for twitter it's work fine and returning user profile link. But for linkedin no. I think that the reason is in access rights, but I didn't see anything in application. In app I have Share on LinkedIn, Sign In with LinkedIn, Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect but I still have no user profile link in response.

I'm using oauth and it's return name and some other fields